# Pythonic method to sum all the odd-numbered lines in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning Python for a programming placement test I have to take for grad school, and this is literally the first little script I threw together to get a feel for it. My background is mainly C# and PHP, but I can't use either language on the test.

My test script reads in the below text file (test_file1.txt). The even lines contain a sample size, and the odd lines contain "results" for each test in the sample. EOF is marked with a 0. I wanted to read in the file, output the sample size, and sum the results of each test. How would you perform this task with Python? I feel like I was trying to force python to be like PHP or C#, and from my research I guess there are very "Python" ways of doing thigs.

test_file1.txt:

```
3
13 15 18
5 
19 52 87 55 1
4
11 8 63 4
2
99 3
0
```

My simple script:

```
file = open("test_file1.txt", "r")

i=0
for line in file:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        #num is even
        if line == '0':
            #EOF
            print 'End of experiment'   
    else:
        #num is odd
        numList = line.split( )
        numList = [int(x) for x in numList]
        print 'Sample size: ' + str(len(numList)) + ' Results: ' + str(sum(numList))
    i += 1

file.close()
```

My results:

```
Sample size: 3 Results: 46
Sample size: 5 Results: 214
Sample size: 4 Results: 86
Sample size: 2 Results: 102
End of experiment
```

Thanks!

Comment: So this is a test?  And also a code review?

Comment: Use `enumerate` to number the lines: `for i, line in enumerate(file)`

Comment: @sr2222, yeah pretty much (well, a sample test question I came up with out of thin air). I want to compare how I approached this with no prior Python knowledge compared to people who do know Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the file as an iterator, then use [`iterators.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get every second line:

```
from itertools import islice

with open("test_file1.txt", "r") as f:
   for line in islice(f, 1, None, 2):
       nums = [int(n) for n in line.split()]
       print 'Sample size: {}  Results: {}'.format(len(nums), sum(nums))
```

`islice(f, 1, None, 2)` skips the first line (`start=1`), then iterates over all lines (`stop=None`) returning every second line (`step=2`).

This'll work with whatever filesize you throw at it; it won't need any more memory than required by the internal iterator buffer.

Output for your test file:

```
Sample size: 3  Results: 46
Sample size: 5  Results: 214
Sample size: 4  Results: 86
Sample size: 2  Results: 102
```

Comment: Is itertools a 3rd party lib or is it built into Python?

Comment: It is a standard library; it comes with Python. I linked to the documentation for the method in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
with open("test_file1.txt", "r") as inf:
    lines = inf.readlines()
    for l in lines[1::2]:  # read only alternating lines
        numList = map(int, line.split())
        print "Sample size:", len(numList), "Results:", sum(numList)
```

Comment: I see the objection @MartijnPieters is making a lot. But I wonder: 1) does it matter? 2) Is the `islice()` method even faster when memory isn't an issue?

Comment: Unless you know absolutely certain the input file is always going to be small, it's best to avoid reading the whole file into memory at once. `islice()` is fully implemented in C, so there is very little overhead using it, and most importantly, it does *not* create a copy of the list. `lines[1::2]` has to create a new list first with all the odd-numbered lines in it, adding 50% more memory usage over the initial list for the file, and creating that list takes time too.

Comment: Not reading the whole file into mem is one thing I tried to avoid doing with my simple solution, but this would be fine as long as you did a check on filesize first to make sure it was < your limit.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this, fairly Pythonic imho:

```
with open('test.txt') as fh:
    for i, line in enumerate(fh):
        if i % 2:
            nums = map(int, line.split())
            print 'Sample size: %d, Results: %d' % (len(nums), sum(nums))
        elif line == '0':
            print 'End of experiment'
```

Comment: I like this solution. Uses built-ins (`enumerate()`) and simple constructs (modulo) so one doesn't need knowledge of `itertools.islice()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how pythonic people may find this, but I find that zip, map, and reduce to be a pretty handy way to do this in a compact way. However, it can be a bit obfuscated.

```
with open("test.txt") as fd:                                                                                                           
   lines = [map(int, s.strip().split()) for s in fd.readlines()]                                                                      
   print "\n".join("Sample Size: %d \t Results: %d"%tuple(map(sum,(d[0],d[1])))                                                       
                   for d in zip(lines, lines[1:], range(len(lines)))                                                                  
                   if d[2] % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: the `tuple` is not needed btw, you can simply do `(...)` instead.

Comment: If you put `(...)` around it is not casting to a tuple, it will just block the order of execution, i.e., as parenthesis. That will cause an error in the string formatting since the format  is looking for a number and the input to format will be a list: `"%d"%(map(...))` will cause an error.